# How to convert string json to PHP?

Tags: php, json, string

```
<?php
$json = '{"data":"listCountry","country":[{"zip":11023,"code":"NY"}],"phone":"+1458589994","name":{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Cannor"},"status":"MEMBER"
}';
$a=json_decode($json);
print_r($a->{'country'}[0]->{'zip'}); //output "11023" Success
echo "<br />";
print_r($a->{'country'}[0]->{'code'}); //output "NY" Success
echo "<br />";
echo $a->phone;  //output "+1458589994" Success
echo "<br />";
echo $a->status;  //output "MEMBER" Success
//this my problem
echo "<br />";
print_r($a->{'name'}[0]->{'firstname'}); //output blank or error
echo "<br />";
print_r($a->{'name'}[0]->{'lastname'}); //output blank or error
?>
```

how do I retrieve the json string **"name": {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Cannor"}** to php in my json ?
i am put php code

```
print_r($a->{'name'}[0]->{'firstname'});
```

and

```
print_r($a->{'name'}[0]->{'lastname'});
```

is error or blank page

Comment: You don't need the braces and quotes for the property names when they're single words. You really only need them when it's non-standard properties such as `this-property` or `this property`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$json = '{"data":"listCountry","country":[{"zip":11023,"code":"NY"}],"phone":"+1458589994","name":{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Cannor"},"status":"MEMBER"
}';
$a=json_decode($json, true);
echo $a['name']['firstname'];
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

name is not a array.

try

```
print_r($a->{'name'}->{'lastname'})
```

Comment: Remember that print_r () function is only neccesary to print a array, For print strings you can use echo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
print_r($a->{'name'}->{'firstname'});
```

You can also simplify your code:

```php
print_r($a->name->firstname);
```

`$a->name` is not an array in your JSON.